# How to count the number of production in SQL

Tags: sql

I just have a problem in my SQL assignment.

I have to list all employees who earned more than $3000.00 in my data.

These are my tables

```
 EMPLOYEE Table  
    EMP_NUM EMP_NAME                JOB_CLASS  
        101 John G. News            Database Designer
        102 David H. Senior         Systems Analyst
        103 June E. Arbough         Electrical Engineer
        104 Anne K. Ramoras         Systems Analyst
        105 Alice K. Johnson        Database Designer
        106 William Smithfield      Programmer
        107 Maria D. Alonzo         Programmer
        108 Ralph B. Washington     Systems Analyst
        111 Geoff B. Wabash         Clerical Support
        112 Darlene M. Smithson     DSS Analyst
        113 Delbert K. Joenbrood    Applications Designer
        114 Annelise Jones          Applications Designer
        115 Travis B. Bawangi       Systems Analyst
        118 James J. Frommer        General Support

ASSIGN Table
EMP_NUM  PROJ_NUM  HOURS
101      15        19.4
102      15        23.8
103      15        23.8
105      15        35.7
106      15        12.6
104      18        32.4
112      18        44
114      18        24.6
118      18        45.3
104      22        48.4
105      22        64.7
106      22        12.8
111      22        22
113      22        23.6
101      25        56.3
107      25        24.6
108      25        23.6
112      25        41.4
114      25        33.1
115      25        45.8
118      25        30.5

JOB Table
JOB_CLASS               CHG_HOUR
Applications Designer   48.1
Clerical Support        26.87
Database Designer       105
DSS Analyst             45.95
Electrical Engineer     84.5
General Support         18.36
Programmer              35.75
Systems Analyst         96.75
```

For previous question which is listing all employees working on multiple projects, I did like this

```
select COUNT (a.PROJ_NUM), e.EMP_NAME
from EMPLOYEE e, ASSIGN a
where e.EMP_NUM = a.EMP_NUM
Having COUNT (a.PROJ_NUM) >= 2
group by e.EMP_NAME;
```

this code gave me what I wanted

What I have trouble with now is getting list who earned more than 3000.00

So I did like this

```
select COUNT (a.HOURS * j.CHG_OUR), e.EMP_NAME
from EMPLOYEE e, ASSIGN a. JOB j
where j.JOB_CLASS = e.JOB_CLASS
and e.EMP_NUM = a.EMP_NUM
Having COUNT (a.HOURS * j.CHG_OUR) >= 3000
group by e.EMP_NAME;
```

But this time, this code did not give me what I wanted

It only printed out error message like this

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 60 Column: 26
```

If you know how to fix it, please answer me

Thank you

Comment: Just a quick note, you probably want > 3000, not >= 3000 (if the assignment is to show greater than 3000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
select COUNT (a.HOURS * j.CHG_OUR), e.EMP_NAME
from EMPLOYEE e, ASSIGN a. JOB j
where j.JOB_CLASS = e.JOB_CLASS
and e.EMP_NUM = a.EMP_NUM
group by e.EMP_NAME;
Having COUNT ((a.HOURS * j.CHG_OUR) >= 3000)
```

I added an extra set of parens around your count.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your HAVING statement must occur after your GROUP BY not before.
2. You don't want to use the COUNT() aggregation, you want SUM().

Something like this:

```
 select SUM (a.HOURS * j.CHG_OUR), e.EMP_NAME
            from EMPLOYEE e, ASSIGN a. JOB j
            where j.JOB_CLASS = e.JOB_CLASS
            and e.EMP_NUM = a.EMP_NUM
            group by e.EMP_NAME
            Having SUM (a.HOURS * j.CHG_OUR) >= 3000;
```

Comment: Hi, Kyle, thanks for replying.  for ur #1 answer, then why did my first code work even my having statement occur before my group by statement?  And may I ask you how to use SUM() aggregation?

Comment: I just found that I put period after ASSIGN a. so I fixed it to comma and now I have error message which said ORA-00904: "J"."CHG_OUR": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 64 Column: 23

Comment: Hi Noel, ye I just found it lol, so I fixed it now I hvae invalid identifier error

Comment: Again, this time, I made typo at j.CHG_OUR lol.  It suppose to be j.CHG_HOUR;; It makes me looks like so silly.  Now I get it. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```
select SUM(a.HOURS * j.CHG_OUR), e.EMP_NAME
from EMPLOYEE e, ASSIGN a, JOB j
where j.JOB_CLASS = e.JOB_CLASS
and e.EMP_NUM = a.EMP_NUM
group by e.EMP_NAME
Having sum(a.HOURS * j.CHG_OUR) >= 3000;
```

Comment: It may be a typo but... Check your `from` clause: You're writing `ASSIGN a. JOB j` use comma instead: `ASSIGN a, JOB j`

Comment: ye those typos... I should double check next time.  Once again, thank you!